# OnClickListener in NavigationDrawer isn't working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

i'm still learning about android developing, so i need little help about making this to work. Application is working, but onclicklistener on navigationDrawer list isn't working.

Here's the code of mainActivity:

```
    package com.dusandimitrijevic.spisakzakupovinu;



import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.dusandimitrijevic.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.dusandimitrijevic.fragments.FragmentMojSpisak;
import com.dusandimitrijevic.fragments.FragmentProizvodi;
import com.dusandimitrijevic.fragments.FragmentSearch;
import com.dusandimitrijevic.model.NavDrawerItem;
import com.tabs.dusandimitrijevic.SlidingTabLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
    private static final int MOJ_SPISAK = 0;
    private static final int PROIZVODI = 1;
    private static final int PROIZVODI_PRETRAGA = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // NavigationDrawer Title
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Spisak za kupovinu
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Notifikacije
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Sacuvan liste
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Prodavnice, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "6"));
        // Podesavanja
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // O nama, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter); 

        // ActionBarTitle
            SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Spisak za kupovinu");
            s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "MyTypeface.otf"), 0, s.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        // settings for toolbar         
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        // setting the actionBar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name
                ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                // on first time display view for first nav item
                displayView(0);
        }


        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        //podešavanja za tabove
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab_view, R.id.tabText);
        mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        mTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
        mTabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.accentColor));
        mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);


    };

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
            break;
        case 1:
            intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
            break;
        case 2:
            intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
            break;
        case 3:
            intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
            break;
        case 4:
            intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
            break;
        case 5:
            intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (intent != null) {

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{


        int icons[] = {R.drawable.ic_action,R.drawable.ic_action_1, R.drawable.ic_actio_2 };
        String[] tabs;


        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            tabs=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int num) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch(num){
                case MOJ_SPISAK:
                    fragment = FragmentMojSpisak.newInstance("", "");
                    break;
                case PROIZVODI:
                    fragment = FragmentProizvodi.newInstance("", "");
                    break;
                case PROIZVODI_PRETRAGA:
                    fragment = FragmentSearch.newInstance("", "");
                    break;          
            }
            return fragment;

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {


            Drawable drawable = getDrawable(icons[position]);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 90, 90);
            ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable);
            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(" ");
            spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            return spannableString;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 3;
        }       
    }
}
```

EDIT:

This is the code of SubActivity:

```
    package com.dusandimitrijevic.spisakzakupovinu;

import com.dusandimitrijevic.fragments.FragmentProizvodi;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SubActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        String prosledjenNaslov = getIntent().getExtras().getString("naslov");
        String prosledjenTekst = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tekst");
        int prosledjenBroj = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("numero");

        TextView naslov = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView broj = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        naslov.setText(prosledjenNaslov);
        tekst.setText(prosledjenTekst);
        broj.setText(""+prosledjenBroj);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sub, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

And this is the code of one Fragment:

```
    package com.dusandimitrijevic.fragments;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.dusandimitrijevic.spisakzakupovinu.DBHelper;
import com.dusandimitrijevic.spisakzakupovinu.DodajProizvodListAdapter;
import com.dusandimitrijevic.spisakzakupovinu.MainActivity;
import com.dusandimitrijevic.spisakzakupovinu.R;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link FragmentMojSpisak#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentMojSpisak extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentMojSpisak.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentMojSpisak newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentMojSpisak fragment = new FragmentMojSpisak();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public FragmentMojSpisak() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_moj_spisak, container, false);
        final MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.shopping_cart_crash_into_object);
        final EditText unos = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final Button dodajDugme = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        final DodajProizvodListAdapter dpl = new DodajProizvodListAdapter(getActivity());

        dpl.addAll(DBHelper.getConnection(getActivity()).getAllProizvodi());

        lv.setAdapter(dpl);

        dodajDugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonSound.start();
                DBHelper.getConnection(getActivity())
                .saveProizvod(unos.getText().toString());

                ArrayList<String> allProizvodi = DBHelper.getConnection(getActivity()).getAllProizvodi();

                dpl.addAll(allProizvodi);

                unos.setText("");

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Proizvod je dodat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        return view;


    }   

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener( new SlideMenuClickListener())` in your onCreate method. In your code, you're never attaching the click listener to the ListView.

```
package com.dusandimitrijevic.spisakzakupovinu;



import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.dusandimitrijevic.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.dusandimitrijevic.fragments.FragmentMojSpisak;
import com.dusandimitrijevic.fragments.FragmentProizvodi;
import com.dusandimitrijevic.fragments.FragmentSearch;
import com.dusandimitrijevic.model.NavDrawerItem;
import com.tabs.dusandimitrijevic.SlidingTabLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
    private static final int MOJ_SPISAK = 0;
    private static final int PROIZVODI = 1;
    private static final int PROIZVODI_PRETRAGA = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // NavigationDrawer Title
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Spisak za kupovinu
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Notifikacije
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Sacuvan liste
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Prodavnice, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "6"));
        // Podesavanja
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // O nama, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter); 
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // ActionBarTitle
            SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Spisak za kupovinu");
            s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "MyTypeface.otf"), 0, s.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        // settings for toolbar         
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        // setting the actionBar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name
                ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                // on first time display view for first nav item
                displayView(0);
        }


        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        //podešavanja za tabove
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab_view, R.id.tabText);
        mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        mTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
        mTabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.accentColor));
        mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);


    };

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
            break;
        case 1:
            intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
            break;
        case 2:
            intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
            break;
        case 3:
            intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
            break;
        case 4:
            intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
            break;
        case 5:
            intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (intent != null) {

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{


        int icons[] = {R.drawable.ic_action,R.drawable.ic_action_1, R.drawable.ic_actio_2 };
        String[] tabs;


        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            tabs=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int num) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch(num){
                case MOJ_SPISAK:
                    fragment = FragmentMojSpisak.newInstance("", "");
                    break;
                case PROIZVODI:
                    fragment = FragmentProizvodi.newInstance("", "");
                    break;
                case PROIZVODI_PRETRAGA:
                    fragment = FragmentSearch.newInstance("", "");
                    break;          
            }
            return fragment;

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {


            Drawable drawable = getDrawable(icons[position]);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 90, 90);
            ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable);
            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(" ");
            spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            return spannableString;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 3;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: In my method displayView i have set to take me to the other activity, but it's only changing the title in actionbar. How to move to the other activity. I was following one tutorial for creating this navigation drawer and there they were creating fragments activity, but i don't want that.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic You're not calling startActivity in your setView method. See my edit

Comment: I'm emberassed. How i forgot that. Sorry for being noob and asking all this questions. I will try to improve in future i hope.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic No need to be embarrassed. We've all been there at some point. Please accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Sorry, but i have one more question. I'm getting one error: 07-02 16:13:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(26602): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dusandimitrijevic.spisakzakupovinu/com.dusandimitrijevic.spisakzakupovinu.SubActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: That's more than likely happening in one of your fragments. I can't really tell you what's wrong without looking at the code. You're most likely calling getString on null arguments. Before calling args.getString(), you need to check if (args != null)

Comment: I have edited my question and provided you the code of my SubActivity. I'm testing only one activity for now, but later i will intent to my fragments activity, so i added also the code of one fragment activity.